# How to keep Report parameters in Exported pdf/excel in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

when i export my SSRS report to excel / pdf format, i want to show my parameters. is there a way to get it directly.

thanks,
NB

Answer (score 4):

The report parameters are not rendered at all in the Excel file.  In order to pass them to the excel file, you will need to display them on the report itself.

One way to do this, is to display the report parameters in the footer of the report.  When exported to excel, they will also be displayed in the footer.

Comment: I can do this way, but i have 20-30 reports so it wil take lot of time to change all those reports..thanks for your help...

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  This will be a boring time consuming job for sure.  Give it to the intern  :)